# Background service not running when screen is off

Tags: android

I am using WakeLock but it consues a lot of battery. Is there any alternate solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of `WakeLock` is to allow the device to run some code instead of going into sleep mode. And whatever way you're using to prevent device from sleeping, its going to consume battery. As far as I know the only way to run code while "screen is off", is to use `WakeLock`.

Android OS is very aggressive about power consumption, and unless you explicitly request to run you application when device is going to power save mode, it will "pause" your app process.

---

So, if you think you must run your code all the time, you should accept battery drain. If app drains too much battery, then consider changing your design and/or decision about how often and how long your app runs, especially when device tries to enter power saving mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement `thread` inside service with `infinite loop` but when you stop service don't forget to release all the resources you have used in service as android does not do it for you.

Comment: I m using thread but when screen is off then service doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Async Tasking:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html